# Is it semantically correct to have <nav></nav> tags inside of an <aside></aside> tag?

Tags: html

I've been wondering about this for the past few days and thought I should register on this website since most of the answers I'm looking for come from here. I wasn't able to find this answer, however.

I'm just wondering if it's semantically correct to nest the nav tag in an aside tag? I'm brand new to the HTML5 scene from XHTML.

```
<aside>
    <nav id="locations">
        An Arizona City Here
        An Arizona Mountain Range
        An Arizona Destination Here
        Somewhere Arizona
        Tucson Location
        Bisbee Location Etc...
    </nav>
</aside>
```

Comment: "Morally"? Might want to try http://philosophy.stackexchange.com instead there... ;-)

Comment: What's the use case for wanting to do this?

Comment: Of course, since I'm a new member, I can't paste in the a href around the text that's shown in the nav block there...

Comment: Sure you can, if you mark it as code.

Comment: "semantically" I think the w3c states that nav is meant to be used for primary navigation, or important nav items only.  Which theoretically puts it at odds with aside - but IMO, as long as you are marking up your site in a consistent manner, and the "semantics" are self-explanitory, you can use these particular tags in conjunction as you wish.

Answer (score 4):

[Yes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-aside-element.html) as long as it is an aside to the content of the elements around it. If you are using it as "this is on the side of my main content in a column type area" then no, it is not appropriate. The semantics of the element is for content that is related to the main content, but not a part of it. You can read more on the w3c site [that has "translated" the spec for web developers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-aside-element.html). It explains some example uses.